# PHP Search Filter on different pages

Tags: php, search, filter, linker

I'm trying to get my different search filters to pop up on different pages. I have an example here:

```
<?php
    if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'bedrijfsaanbod') {
    include_once(VIEW_PATH . '/includes/filter.bedrijfsaanbod.php');
    } else {
    include_once(VIEW_PATH . '/includes/filter.makelaars.php');
    }
    ?>
```

That is what I came up with so far. The problem however is that my URL changes as soon as the search gets conducted, which means it'll automatically show the /includes/filter.makelaars.php again. Any tips on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: add condition to exclude url from the condition when you post data may be?

Comment: Any example on how to exclude?